# Showing that a map can be deformed into the identity.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Suppose $F((a,b), k) = (ae^{\pi i k}, be^{\pi i k})$ where $0 \leq k \leq 1$. Now would  $g(a,b)$ = $(-a,-b)$ if $g : S^{1} \rightarrow S^{1}$?

Comment: What is g? Is it defined somehow?

Comment: $g : S^1 \rightarrow S^1$

Comment: $g$ is an arbitrary continuous functions $S^1 \rightarrow S^1$?

Comment: If g is arbitrary, why would $g(a,b)=(-a,-b)$? And what does $F$ have to do with changing $g$?

Comment: Yes I believe so. Maybe I should not of used the word "deformed" in the problem. The moral of the story is that this map $g$ given by $g(x,y) = (-x,-y)$ is homotopic to the identity map. Now the first sentence above was my attempt at finding a function that would give us what we want.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Show that a rotation of the circle is homotopic to the identity.